# About Integer Datatypes and Promotions

Tags: c

- Platform: Linux 3.2.0 x86 (Debian 7.1)
- Compiler: GCC 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)

I am writing an integer to string conversion function that accepts an integer value(radix) for an argument. The valid range of the integer argument(radix) is extremely small(2-36), smaller than the maximum size of a char. So I want to declare the argument as a char but I have to multiply a long long int by said argument and I am wondering how exactly that works. I do not want to declare the argument as char if that adds anything extra to the calculation process. So my question is what happens when I multiply a long long int by a char in regards to the calculation itself. Also the function writes a small amount of data that is less than the maximum size of an unsigned char at worst case so I want to use a short int to index it because when I try to dereference a pointer using a char I get a warning. So my question is why can pointers not be dereferenced by a char and does using an short int for an index add anything to the dereferencing process or the calculation process when I increase or decrease the index's value by 1. And are those behaviors consistent because I heard that 16 bit integer data types on certain systems are actually less efficient than their 32 bit counterparts in regards to arithmetic but I do not know if that is true.

```
int integer_conversion(long long int integer, char *str, short int str_size, char radix)
{
    //'i' is the index variable I was talking about.
short int i = 1;
long long int radix_place = 1;

if(str == NULL) return -1;
if(str_size <= 0) return -2;

if(integer < 0)
{
            //radix_place(long long int) * radix(char)
    for(; integer / radix_place <= -radix; radix_place *= radix, i++);
    i++;

    if(i > str_size) return -4;

    str[i] = '\000';
    i--;

    if(radix >= 2 && radix <= 10)
    {
        for(; i >= 1; i--)
        {
                            //integer(long long int) mod radix(char)
            str[i] = -(integer % radix) + '0';
                            //integer(long long int) / radix(char)
            integer /= radix;
        }
    }
    else if(radix >= 11 && radix <= 36)
    {
        for(; i >= 1; i--)
        {
                            //integer(long long int) mod radix(char)
            str[i] = -(integer % radix);

                            //Is any type of conversion or promotion preformed here?
            if(str[i] <= 9) str[i] += '0';
            else str[i] += '7';

                            //integer(long long int) / radix(char)
            integer /= radix;
        }
    }
    else return 2354;

    str[0] = '-';
}
else
{
            //radix_place(long long int) * radix(char)
    for(; integer / radix_place >= radix; radix_place *= radix, i++);

    if(i > str_size) return -4;

    str[i] = '\000';
    i--;

    if(radix >= 2 && radix <= 10)
    {
        for(; i >= 0; i--)
        {
                            //integer(long long int) mod radix(char)
            str[i] = integer % radix + '0';
                            //integer(long long int) / radix(char)
            integer /= radix;
        }
    }
    else if(radix >= 11 && radix <= 36)
    {
        for(; i >= 0; i--)
        {
                            //integer(long long int) mod radix(char)
            str[i] = integer % radix;

                            //Is any type of conversion or promotion preformed here?
            if(str[i] <= 9) str[i] += '0';
            else str[i] += '7';

                            //integer(long long int) / radix(char)
            integer /= radix;
        }
    }
    else return 2354;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't worry about efficiency — especially efficiency from choosing the right size of integer — until after you've written the code and actually *need* to make it more efficient.  Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @Aniket You are right I just updated the question. jwodder the function is done for the most part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two parts to this:

1. Efficiency.  On a modern processor, there are no efficiency gains to declaring types shorter than `int` in most places, such as function parameters and local variables.  Maybe `char` or `unsigned char` parameters would be useful if you are writing for a small microcontroller.
2. Correctness.  All integer types (including `char`) will first get promoted to `int`, unless they don't fit, in which case they get promoted to `unsigned int`, unless they don't fit.  Then the "usual arithmetic conversions" promote both types in most operations to the same type.

Here's an example:

```
char c;
long long x;
return c * x;
```

In this case, the result is:

```
return ((long long) c) * x;
```

(Unless, perhaps, `sizeof(long long) == 1`, `CHAR_BIT == 64`, and `char` is unsigned by default.  But that is a downright pathological case.)

### Recommendation

Use `int` instead of `short`.

```
int integer_conversion(long long int integer, char *str, int str_size, int radix)
{
    // don't bother with "short"
    int i = 1;
    long long int radix_place = 1;

    if(str == NULL) return -1;
    if(str_size <= 0) return -2;
```